# The unexpected behavior of FindMinimumCostFlow?

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

## Bugs(the fourth and fifth behavior) is present in V10.4.1

---

I'm at a loss to understand the behavior of the `FindMinimumCostFlow` function. Here are a few cases I find confusing.

## First Behavior

```
g = Graph[
      {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 2 -> 4}, 
      {VertexLabels -> {Placed["Name", Center]}, 
      VertexSize -> {0.3}, VertexStyle -> {GrayLevel[1]}}
    ]
```

[image]

```
f = FindMinimumCostFlow[g, {10, 0, 0, -10}, "OptimumFlowData"];
f["CostValue"]
f["FlowGraph"]
```

[image]

How to understand the $20$? I think the cost value should be 2 as the documentation on **Details and Options**.

> With the default setting EdgeCost->Automatic, the cost per unit flow
>   on an edge is taken to be the EdgeCost in the graph g if available,
>   otherwise 1.

## Second Behavior

```
FindMinimumCostFlow[g, 1, 4, 1.5]
```

> 3.

How to understand this 3? I think it should be 4, because the flow goes through four edges.

[image]

## Third Behavior

This is an example from the documentation. The original cost value reported in the saved docs is 2. When you run the code, it will return $0.6$.

[image]

I think the original value is right, because the `Edgecost` is `Automatic`

[image]

But I am not sure which result should be given.

---

## Updating for other two cases

As the Wjx's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119404/21532),the behavior from first to third seem to no problem.But I found other strange behaviors.

## Fourth Behavior

I can sure this is a bug attribution--`"FlowValue"`,The screenshoot from [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimumCostFlow.html)
[image]

## Fifth Behavior

From [that comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119088/the-unexpected-behavior-of-findminimumcostflow#comment323000_119404) I gave

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 3 <-> 4}, 
  EdgeCapacity -> {0.4, 0.6, 0.9, 0.7}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]; SetProperty[g, 
 EdgeLabels -> 
  MapThread[Rule, {EdgeList[g], PropertyValue[g, EdgeCapacity]}]]
FindMinimumCostFlow[g, 1, 3]
FindMinimumCostFlow[g, 1, 3, "FlowGraph"]
```

[image]

The $1.7$ is expected but $1.4$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## This IS NOT A BUG but do IS A BUG as well.

### This is not a BUG at first, but I found a serious BUG while trying to persuade @yode it's not a BUG.

I think I've got an explanation for this problem:

First thing first, Let's first check our documentation:

It said that when setting `EdgeCost` to `Automatic` **cost per unit flow** on an edge is taken to be 1. Thus we can know that the calculation of **Cost** is given by multiplying **EdgeCost** with **EdgeFlow** and finally sum them up!!!

Thus for the first situation, as there're **10 units** of flow to deliver while each unit will go through **2 edges** so the final cost shall be **20**, not *2*.

The second problem can be solved the same way: as there're **1.5 units** of flow to deliver while each unit will go through **2 edges** so the final cost shall be **3**, not *4*.

The third is a bit intriguing: it seems that in order to get a maximum flow, it shall flow through the upper part with **0.3** intensity while flow through the 0.9 edge with **0.9** intensity. So the total should be **0.3*2+0.9=1.5** instead of **0.6** which we get. How?

First let's show the **FullForm** of that Graph, the useful part is shown below:

```
Graph[List[1, 2, 3, 4], 
 List[DirectedEdge[1, 2], DirectedEdge[2, 3], DirectedEdge[3, 1], 
  DirectedEdge[3, 4]], 
 Rule[EdgeCapacity, List[0.3`, 0.6`, 0.9`, 0.7`]]]
```

It's actually an **Directed Graph**!!!!!

[image: this is the true graph]

So the flow can only go through the upper part thus the result should be **0.3*2=0.6** Great!
So the result is correct, but the reference's stored result, maybe because of some early versions' bug, is left wrong.

Problem solved~

Hope this explanation can help you~~

---

## Edit1

I think I've found something wrongly stated in reference.

It said that when setting EdgeCapacity to `Automatic`, it means `Infinity`. But how can a graph with infinity flow get a not infinity cost? In real situations, I think it will automatically set them to `1` Instead. Why not check the reference out~ The first example it gives shows this: The `FullForm` of this graph is without any specification on `EdgeCapacity` While the result is 9 and the flow will go in a way that ensures every edge's flowcount is 1, which means the edges are probably with `EdgeCapacity` of `1`.

But for the fourth example @yode gives, I really have no idea what's going on......

---

## Edit2

Now I'm totally confused about the fourth and the fifth situation:

Check this two graphs out:

```
g1=Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 3 <-> 4}, 
 EdgeCapacity -> {.6, .6, .6, .7}]
g2=Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 3 <-> 4}, 
 EdgeCapacity -> {.6, .6, .9, .7}]

FindMinimumCostFlow[g1, 1, 3]
FindMinimumCostFlow[g2, 1, 3]

(*1.8*)
(*1.8*)
```

How is that possible for us to change one edge's capacity, while the edge is the shortest connection between source and the end, without influencing the cost?

Still more mysterious:

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}, 
  EdgeCapacity -> {.6, .6, .0, .7}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

f = FindMinimumCostFlow[g, 1, 4, "OptimumFlowData"];
f["FlowGraph"]
f["CostValue"]
f["FlowValue"]
```

It actually find a solution that flow through an edge with 0 Capacity!!!!!

That must be a bug......

---

## Edit3

The "FlowValue" is really a **HUGE** bug I suppose, It kept 0 in thousands of trials with random graphs.

```
Quiet@DeleteCases[
  Table[FindMinimumCostFlow[RandomGraph[RandomInteger[50, 2]], 1, 2, 
    "FlowValue"], 1000], Except[_Integer]]
```

This program returns only **0**. I have nothing to say about that......

---

## Edit4 This edit is probably the most IMPORTANT edit

### ----An explanation for problem 5

"...A whole set of relationship errors, which, when I started digging into them, it looks almost like a checklist for a sex therapist or a couples counselor. You sort of get down there to the bottom and things get really dicey."------From a TED Talk

When I found this bug, I'm extremely frustrated.

```
FindMinimumCostFlow[
 Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3}, 
  EdgeCapacity -> {1, 0, .5}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"], 1, 3, "FlowGraph"]
```

This code runs quite well, the result, `2`, is quite reasonable if you have read my previous explanation.

Then, the second code runs out quite well too, seemingly reasonable:

```
FindMinimumCostFlow[
 Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 1, 2 <-> 3}, 
  EdgeCapacity -> {1, 0, .5}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"], 1, 3, "FlowGraph"]
```

after all, 1<->3 is the same thing as 3<->1

but it's not quite pleasant when the third code generate the same result:

```
FindMinimumCostFlow[
 Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3}, 
  EdgeCapacity -> {1, 0, .5}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"], 1, 3, "FlowGraph"]
```

I've already changed the position of edges, so if we want to get a proper result, we'll have to change `EdgeCapacity` accordingly. but without changing it, we get an IDENTICAL RESULT!!!!!! That's not normal, indicating that while assigning EdgeCapacity, the Graph automatically changed the vertex's order, some sort of `Sort` it. and that's the reason, I suppose, why it generates the wrong result!!!

Also, after changing the order of `EdgeCapacity` rules, it generates the correct result!!

```
FindMinimumCostFlow[
 Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3}, 
  EdgeCapacity -> {1, .5, 0}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"], 1, 3, "FlowGraph"]
```

Maybe this bug will exist in other functions related to this as well, let's sort them out.

---

### SO here's the final solution for question 5, simply change the order of `EdgeCapacity` will make the result correct......

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 3 <-> 4}, 
  EdgeCapacity -> {0.4, 0, 0.6, 0.7}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]; SetProperty[g, 
 EdgeLabels -> 
  MapThread[Rule, {EdgeList[g], PropertyValue[g, EdgeCapacity]}]]
FindMinimumCostFlow[g, 1, 3]
FindMinimumCostFlow[g, 1, 3, "FlowGraph"]
```

This will generate the correct result of `.8` and a correct flowgraph as well, while using the normal order won't.

It seems that it's sorting in a rather odd way, maybe someone can comeout and explain it a bit further, with @yode's graph, here's what the result seems to tell us:

```
{{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4} -> 
  0.8, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3} -> 
  0.8, {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4} -> 
  0.8, {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3} -> 
  0.8, {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3} -> 
  0.8, {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3} -> 
  0.8, {2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4} -> 
  0.8, {2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3} -> 
  0.8, {2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4} -> 
  0.4, {2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 2} -> 
  0.4, {2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3} -> 
  0.8, {2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2} -> 
  0.4, {1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4} -> 
  0.4, {1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3} -> 
  0.4, {1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4} -> 
  0.4, {1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 2} -> 
  0.4, {1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3} -> 
  0.4, {1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2} -> 
  0.4, {3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3} -> 
  0.8, {3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3} -> 
  0.8, {3 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3} -> 
  0.8, {3 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2} -> 
  0.4, {3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3} -> 
  0.4, {3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 2} -> 0.4}
```

I hope the bug lists can end here...... I really don't like to see a swarm of bug flying in those bottom level functions, these make me really uncomfortable.

Comment: Upvote for your very resonable analysis

Comment: But how to understand the $1.4$ if we change it into `Undirected Graph`?`g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 3 <-> 4}, 
   EdgeCapacity -> {0.4, 0.6, 0.9, 0.7}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
SetProperty[g, 
  EdgeLabels -> 
   MapThread[Rule, {EdgeList[g], PropertyValue[g, EdgeCapacity]}]];
FindMinimumCostFlow[g, 1, 3]`

Comment: For this problem, I still have no idea what's going on at this point......

Comment: 2018, Version 11,3. 
"FlowValue" still wrong.

Comment: February 2023, Version 13.2.1, still wrong. I actually lost quite some time on trying to "fix" a FlowValue of 0. Damn, wolfram!

Comment: @WaterFox Be sure to report it [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimumCostFlow.html) (at the bottom).