# Can FindMinimumCostFlow be trusted?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

So, I recently began to use graphs algorithms in Mathematica notebooks to solve an unbalanced assignment problem.
After running the algorithm, I wanted to check that the total flow was equal to the number of categories, that is writing something like

```
Assert[flowData["FlowValue"] == 7 ]
```

However this broke my code. After some investigation, any `FlowValue` I could retrieve was null. After more investigation, I found this is actually documented [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119088/the-unexpected-behavior-of-findminimumcostflow): in short, we can reproduce the bug with the following, that returns always 0:

```
Quiet@DeleteCases[
  Table[FindMinimumCostFlow[RandomGraph[RandomInteger[50, 2]], 1, 2, 
    "FlowValue"], 1000], Except[_Integer]]
```

Great, I can comment my now-useless assertion.

However, I still need the other data returned by `"OptimumFlowData"`:

- `flowData["FlowGraph"]`
- `flowData["CostValue"]`
- `flowData["EdgeList"]`
- `flowData["VertexList"]`

Can I trust those fields or have they been shown to have bugs too? I begin to wonder if Mathematica was actually the right choice for this graph problem.

[Edit] I did file a bug report